# Drupal Commerce Product SKU pane not showing after upgrade

Tags: commerce, panels

After performing an upgrade of a Drupal 7 site (core and modules), including Drupal Commerce, the Product SKU pane is not showing up on my panels page.  I'm able to add it to my panels page and there are SKU's for the product.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:  I've found setting the View Mode to "Product List" makes this appear correctly.